# How to transfer nft from one account to another via web3?

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation

I use the `erc1155` type and I can't get `nft` on my other account, after confirming the transaction, nothing happens.

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0xTARGET_TOKEN');

const safeTransferFrom = contract.methods.safeTransferFrom(
    from_address,
    '0xTARGET_TOKEN',
    nft_transaction_token_id,
    1,
    [],
);

const last_block = await web3.eth.getBlock("latest");
const gas_limit = Math.floor(last_block.gasLimit / last_block.transactions.length);

const result = await safeTransferFrom.send({
    from: from_address,
    gas: gas_limit,
});
```

I tried safe translation and the same `setApproveForAll` but it doesn’t work for me, the documentation is very poor and I didn’t find anything except for the interface for the contract.

[Docs for ERC1155 `safeTransferFrom`](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc1155#ERC1155-safeTransferFrom-address-address-uint256-uint256-bytes-)

Answer (score 0):

Considering:

`safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 id, uint256 amount, bytes data) public`

Instead of providing the `to` address of the wallet you want to transfer the token to, you're providing the `'0xTARGET_TOKEN'` (token address).

Also, if you want to provide a more accurate gas limit for the transaction, I suggest using the `estimateGas` method.

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-estimategas

```js
const safePercentage = 1.2;
const method1 = contractInstance.methods.method1(obj)
const gasEstimate = await method1.estimateGas({ from: account })
let gasLimit = Math.round(gasEstimate * safePercentage);
```

Comment: the error was that I specified the wrong contract address when creating the contract, thus the transaction did not go through, you need to specify the ABI and the contract address so that everything goes well